# Как изменить/задать цвет ячейки в Google Spreadsheets с помощью POST-запроса?

Tags: php, google-api, google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Я использую PHP для обращения к API Google. Скрипт аутентифицируется и читает/вставляет строки замечательно, проблема именно в задании форматирования.

Ссылка выглядит вот так:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/<...spreadID...>/od6/private/full
```

Тело запроса в xml:

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended">
    <gsx:номер color="#FF0000">номер адин</gsx:номер>
</entry>
```

Ячейка с текстом **"Номер адин"** появляется, но как задать цвет - без понятия. Атрибут `color`, как оказалось, не помогает. Уже весь интернет перерыл, не знаю, что делать.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать bgcolor || background || backgroundcolor вместо colot

Comment: bgcolor пробовали??? Правда с googleAPI я не знаком к сожалению. Но судя из соображений то можно попробовать!

Comment: Добрые люди подсказывают, что через протокол - никак. Через AppScript - пожалуйста https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

Answer (score 1):

Да, в итоге выяснилось, что ячейки предвычислены и через `API` изменить их формат нельзя. Я сделал так:

1. Настроил ежедневный `cron`. `PHP` отправляет данные, а затем вставляет в одну из ячеек номера и количество строк в виде `1_2;4_6` и т.д.
2. Написал `AppScript` и настроил его через триггеры на ежедневный запуск после `cron'a`. Он парсит эту ячейку и форматирует строки как мне нужно, вставляя пустую строку в начало таблицы, чтобы `PHP` добавлял информацию сверху.
3. Есть нюанс. Строка №1 - заголовки, они не меняются, взять их значения просто так нельзя. Чтобы отправить данные в нужные столбцы, мне пришлось заполнить строку №2 пробелами в нужных местах. Перед отправкой я беру эту строку и записываю заголовки в массив. Поэтому полезные данные начинаются со строки №3. Может, у кого есть идеи, как этого избежать? Хотя этот костыль неплохо работает.
4. Еще один нюанс. При вставке в начало таблицы (перед пустой строкой и после строки с пробелами), новые строки форматируются так же, как пустая строка. Поэтому формат я сразу настроил в первой строке, а в `AppScript` копирую его в пустую строку.

`AppScript` (может, кому пригодится):

```
var del = {// разделители строка-количество и блоков
  row  : '_',
  block: ';'
};
var mcol = {// столбцы для объединения
  date: 4,
  pay : 9,
  paid: 10
};

var user_col   = 8;
var row        = 3;// строка с настройками
var bgnd_color = '#8cff8a';// цвет строки-разделителя

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();


//====================================== Main
function main()
{
  // если еще не форматировали - объединяем нужные ячейки
  if (Format())
  {
    // вставляем в начало (после первой) пустую строку
    sheet.insertRows(row);

    // пустая строка
    var new_row = sheet.getRange(row, 2, 1, 10);// row, B, 1row, 10cols

    // берем формат первой строки и применяем к пустой,
    // чтобы данные от PHP правильно форматировались
    sheet.getRange(row-1, 2, 1, 10)
         .copyTo(new_row, {formatOnly: true});// row-1, B, 1row, 10cols
  }
}


//====================================== Formatting
function Format()
{
  var pos = GetCell(row, mcol.date);
  var result = false;

  if (pos)
  {
    pos = pos.toString();

    // разделы по пользователям
    pos = In(pos, del.block) ? pos.split(del.block) : [pos];

    for (var i=0; i<pos.length; i++)
    {
      var rows = pos[i];

      // "первая строка" - "количество"
      rows = In(rows, del.row) ? rows.split(del.row) : [rows, 1];

      var start_row = parseInt(rows[0],10);
      var count     = parseInt(rows[1],10);

      // если больше одной строки - объединяем даты, счета, и оплаты
      if (count > 1)
        for (var type in mcol)
          sheet.getRange(start_row, mcol[type], count)
               .mergeVertically();

      // форматируем имя менеджера
      sheet.getRange(start_row-1, user_col, 1)
           .setFontWeight('bold')
           .setHorizontalAlignment('center');

      if (i == pos.length-1)// последний блок - закрашиваем границу за ним
        sheet.getRange(start_row+count, 2, 1, 10)
             .setBackground(bgnd_color);
    }

    ClearCell(row, mcol.date);
    result = true;
  }

  return result;
}

//====================================== Other
function In(str, v)
{
 return str.indexOf(v) != -1;
}

function GetCell(row, col)
{
  return sheet.getSheetValues(row, col, 1, 1)[0][0];
}

function ClearCell(row, col)
{
  sheet.getRange(row, col, 1, 1)
       .clear({contentsOnly: true});
}
```